# Why does the alpha particle not excite the isovector transitions in nuclei?

Tags: nuclear-physics, isospin-symmetry

The $\alpha$ particle is a very commonly used projectile for studying inelastic scattering. It has T=0 ans S=0. But it only excites the isoscalar vibration modes in target nuclei, and not isovector modes. Why is that so? Is it related to the T=0 property of the $\alpha$?
If so, will the 12C projectile also only excite isoscalar modes?

To excite isovector modes, one needs a projectile that can make neutrons and protons oscillate opposite to each other. Should such a projectile have T=1 in its ground state?

Comment: "Should such a projectile have T=1 in its ground state?"  Anything other than isospin 0.

Comment: okay. Suppose I excite the same inelastic state in a nucleus once with α and once with 3He, how would the cross sections vary? Will I be able to separate out the isoscalkar and isovector parts of the scattering?

Comment: My guess is yes, but I'm not an expert on that sort of experimental analysis.